# React-Native How to update parent state variable from child component

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

I am presenting a component using **Modal** in react-native. So in the Child component(the component that is presented on top of parent as Modal) I am trying to update the state variable of parent, but it is throwing error like "**'changeModalVisibility' is missing in props validation**".

Kindly help me to solve this.

Related Code is below:

```
// Parent Class in render
<SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <Modal
          animationType="slide"
          transparent={false}
          visible={this.state.isModalVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => { this.changeModalVisibility(false) }}
        >
          <ChildClass
            changeModalVisibility={this.changeModalVisibility}
          />
        </Modal>
</SafeAreaView>
// Outside Render function
changeModalVisibility = (bool) => {
 this.setState({ isModalVisible: visible });
}

// In Child Class 
<TouchableHighlight
              underlayColor="none"
              onPress={this.props.closeButtonTapped}
              style={{ alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', }}
            >
              <Text style={{
                color: 'white',
                marginTop: 10,
                marginLeft: 20,
                fontWeight: '600',
                fontSize: 18,
              }}
              >Close
              </Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>

closeButtonTapped() {
this.props.changeModalVisibility //"**'changeModalVisibility' is missing in props validation**"
}
```

Comment: This is an [issue with your prop-types](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/prop-types.md), not a functional error.

Comment: Add braces **()** at the end of the method in closeButtonTapped() Method like `this.props.changeModalVisibility()`

Comment: @KaushikRadadiya: Its throwing error "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression. & is missing in props validation"

Comment: Have you tried to pass a parameter with a function call? like this this.props.changeModalVisibility(false)

Comment: @KaushikRadadiya: I have tried and it worked, Thank u bro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Child component in parent component has `changeModalVisibility` prop.
You should call
`this.props.changeModalVisibility(true) or  this.props.changeModalVisibility(false)`
inside child component. Make sure to use arrow function when you want to execute function from prop :

```
changeModalVisibility={this.changeModalVisibility}

changeModalVisibility = (visible) => {
 this.setState({ isModalVisible: visible });
}
```

In child component onPress props should be like this:

```
onPress={() => this.closeButtonTapped()}
```

Comment: I have tried it, it is throwing same error, and method in the parent not getting called

Comment: Answer updated :) You created function and called prop inside onPress.

Comment: Should "changeModalVisibility={this.changeModalVisibility.bind(this)}" this be written in Parent component's constructor method?
I have kept that by keeping in Parent method's constructor and tried to log props in Child Component, empty data is returned and parent method didn't get called

Comment: Yep in parent component.